# Publish a Gmail Add-on

Tags: gmail-addons

I'm planning to launch a simple Gmail Add-on. I've followed every step in
the publishing guide and filled the submission form. **However, it's been
two weeks now and I've yet to receive any response.**

Also, the guide seems wrong, because it instructs users to first fill in
the Marketplace SDK Configuration tab and there is no way to save that
information because the 'Save changes' button is disabled. The changes on
that page are lost once i close the browser. All i can do is fill the submission form. That part is very confusing.

Can anyone please tell me how much time does it take for my submission to be
reviewed? Or what are the steps to publish a public Gmail Add-on...? The ones in the guide don't seem to work.

Comment: Who down voted this question? I'll ask it again in a new post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issues publishing a Gmail Add-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49749192/issues-publishing-a-gmail-add-on)