# Issues publishing a Gmail Add-on

Tags: gmail-addons

I'm planning to launch a simple Gmail Add-on. I've followed every step in the publishing guide and filled the submission form. **However, it's been two weeks now and I've yet to receive any response**.

Can anyone please tell me how much time does it take for my submission to be reviewed? Or what are the steps to publish a public Gmail Add-on...? The ones in the guide don't seem to work.

Also, the guide seems wrong, because it instructs users to first fill in the Marketplace SDK Configuration tab and there is no way to save that information because the 'Save changes' button is disabled. The changes on that page are lost once i close the browser. All i can do is fill the submission form. That part is very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

There definitely is a bug on that page. (can't save "Apps Marketplace SDK" Configuration for Gmail Addon). I have [reported it here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79123714). Add yourself to "I am also facing this issue" list so that the issue gets noticed by Google developers.

Comment: I've done the same a few days ago. But i've yet to receive a response from the dev team. I'm starting to think the Google Add-On project is dead.